# DynamoDB to Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-redshift

I am asking this in context of loading data from DynamoDb into Redshift. Per the [Redshift Docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Loading-data-from-dynamodb.html):

> To avoid consuming excessive amounts of provisioned read throughput, we recommend that you **not load data** from Amazon DynamoDB tables that are in production environments.

My data is in Production, so how do I get it out of there?

Alternately is DynamoDB Streams a better overall choice to move data from DynamoDB into Redshift? (I understand this does not add to my RCU cost.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning is due to the fact that the export could consume much of your read capacity for a period of time, which would impact your production environment.

Some options:

- Do it at night when you don't need as much capacity
- Set `READRATIO` to a low value so that it consumes less of the capacity
- Temporarily increase the Read Capacity Units of the table when performing the export (you can [decrease capacity](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html) four times a day)

DynamoDB Streams provides a stream of data representing changes to a DynamoDB table. You would need to process these streams using AWS Lambda to send the data somewhere for loading into Redshift. For example, you could populate another DynamoDB table and use it for importing into Redshift. Or, you could write the data to Amazon S3 and import from there into Redshift. However, this involves *lots of moving parts*.

Answer (score 0):

Using **AWS Data pipeline**, you can do a  bulk copy data from DynamoDB  to a new or existing Redshift table.

Comment: Bulk copy I am assuming consume RCUs

Comment: Ok so EMR ths solution here as it guarantee HA when copying